# WPF - The buttons next to each other

Tags: wpf

I have button and under him is text and these buttons are next to each other  but are served under him. This is my code:
 UserView.xaml:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment = "Left">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = Users}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation = "Vertical">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource UserButton}" Content="{Binding Name}"></Button>
                        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource UserButtonStatus}" 
                                       Fill="{Binding Color}" ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </WrapPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Title}">Users</TextBlock>
            <view:UserView x:Name="UserView">
                <view:UserView.DataContext>
                    <Binding Path="UserViewModel" Source="{StaticResource ServiceLocator}"/>
                </view:UserView.DataContext>
            </view:UserView>
        </StackPanel>
```

Required:

[image]

Actual (wrong):

[image]

Comment: Provide more code of binding

Comment: May be use Horizontal in '<StackPanel Orientation = "Vertical">' (UserView.xaml)

Comment: No, I have button and under him is text and these buttons are next to each other

Comment: Please revise your question.  As it stands, it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Revised was complete

Comment: change it into <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal"> in MainWindow.xaml

Comment: Is a mistake. This attribute makes it the headline above the buttons. problem is the location of WrapPanel. If i manually write this, then is good <WrapPanel> <StackPanel><Button/></StackPanel><StackPanel><Button/></StackPanel></WrapPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overwrite the items controls panel

items control will display each item underneath each other by default.

here is the code to add make sure its inside your items control tab just like you have done with the item template:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <WrapPanel/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

So your userview.xaml will look like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = Users}">

     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation = "Vertical">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource UserButton}" Content="{Binding Name}"></Button>
                    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource UserButtonStatus}" Fill="{Binding Color}" ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}"/>
               </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```